# Configuring primepush with PF4,GF4 and Atmosphere-2.0.1

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, atmosphere

I am trying to configure primepush in Glassfish4 with primefaces4 and atmosphere 2.0.1. I have my web.xml as:

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>   

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>       
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Comet Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Comet Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_comet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId> 
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0</version> 
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have tried code from forum:
[primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=31540)
and changing atmosphere-runtime. Have I missed something?

I have the following error:

> SEVERE: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined your dependency as provided.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This means that you only want the dependency during compile time, and something else provides the jar at runtime. See [Maven's Scope Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

You'll probably want to use runtime as the atmosphere-runtime artifact is generally only needed at runtime:

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

Or compile if it is needed during compilation:

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```